# iOS MVC Model Naming Convention

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

Is there a standard convention for naming Model classes? I looked [at Apple's conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html), but I really couldn't find an answer, if there is one.  Views are usually prefixed with UI and/or contain view in the name; controllers usually post-fix "controller," but I'm not sure how to name my model classes.  I've seen Manager, but usually these are singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Model* classes typically represent objects of the *real world*, so you'll just name them exactly like those, a few examples:

`Car`
`User`
`Animal`
`House`

Note that *Model* classes are essentially there to provide a logical component of your app's application domain.

You can give prefixes to your classes so that their *namespaces* don't interfere with classes that come  from other projects or frameworks where they might have been named identically. Also, the prefixes that Apple uses usually indicate the framework that these classes come from (although this is not always the case), like `UIViewController`, `UIButton`, `UILabel` etc coming from `UIKit`.

Comment: The real world objects you list make sense, but for my last app I had a class named ParseController.  I am always trying refine things, and I came to the conclusion that this class was really not a controller, but a model object.  This class contained methods for interacting with parse, and had nothing to do with the view.  I think I have fallen into the habit of naming my Model objects controllers, because previously I thought of Models as only static data for some reason.  But now that I have decided its a Model object, it's difficult naming abstract objects.

Comment: indeed, picking the right names isn't all too obvious sometimes... often it helps when you think about if your class is there to _represent_ something (then it might more likely be a model object) or if it's there to take any actions, then it's more likely to be a _controller_, _manager_, _service_ or whatever you want to call it. think about what _specifically_ the objects' responsibilities are and then try to pick a name according to that...

Comment: "what specifically the objects' responsibilities are"  I really like this advice. Recently I have started paying close attention to single responsibility when implementing my classes, but I hadn't given it much thought when naming.  Im the only one who reads my codes, so in the past I just picked a name, but I will ask myself this question when naming classes from now on.

Comment: sure! and as you move forward and develop on larger-scale projects or in professional environments you will notice by yourself that sticking to conventions (and naming is one of them) is actually really important! good luck with everything :)